# Como puedo recargar automáticamente la pagina para que se reflejen los datos usando jsp?

Tags: jsp, servlets

Tengo un problema, estoy trabajando en una pagina que estoy realizando en jsp
el problema que tengo se debe a las peticiones submit ya que al utilizar servlets ya sea para agregar, eliminar, actualizar en ventanas modales y mostrar la tengo en la pagina , tengo que recargar la pagina presionando el botón para mostrar el cual me despliega los datos en una tabla.
Si no presiono ese botón no aparece la lista, aunque haya eliminado, o agregado o actualizado registros, si no presiono el botón para mostrar, la lista no me aparece o bien  no me muestra los datos en la tabla actualizados.

aca dejo imagen de las pantallas.

1.-imagen cuando ingreso a la pagina

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2.-imagen cuando se recarga la pagina para mostrar los datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3.-Imagen cuando se va a agregar un registro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4.- imagen de como se visualiza la tabla después de agregar un registro
aquí el registro nuevo agregado no se visualiza , solo si se presiona el botón para mostrar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

5.-Imagen después de presionar el botón para mostrar
aquí recién se muestra el registro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero saber como podría hacer para que al agregar un registro o eliminar o actualizar , desde las ventanas modal de cada operación, dicha acción haga un refresh para así al retornar a la pagina , las modificaciones se muestren sin tener que presionar dicho botón mostrar. Pero el desarrollo está hecho jsp y necesito una forma que no sea por ajax ni jquery ya que tendría que modificar todo y estoy con muy poco tiempo.
espero me puedan ayudar.

acá dejo el código.

Formulario donde se muestra la tabla con los datos, esta es la que para mostrar se debe presionar el boton.

```
<form method="POST" action="verReservasClienteServlet.do">
<div class="left container-fluid">
<div class="pull-right">
 <%
              for(int i=0; i<usuarioCliente.size(); i++)
                           {
                               out.print("<b style='display:none'>User:</b><input type='text'value="+usuarioCliente.get(i).getIdUsuario()+" class='right' size='4' name='txt_usuarioVerReservaCliente' style='display:none'>");
                           }                        
    %>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary glyphicon-plus" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalReservar2" style="font-size:19px"></button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" style="font-size:19px"></button>
</div>
<div class="panel-heading btn-info" >RESERVAS</div>
<div class="panel-body panel col-lg-12">
 <nav class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
<div class="left container-fluid">
<div class="panel-heading bg-default btn-sm">MIS RESERVAS</div>
<div class="panel-body panel panel-primary table-wrapper-scroll-y">
 <table class="table-condensed table-hover table-responsive" id="resultado">
            <thead class="input-sm">
            <tr>
                <th class="btn-info">N° Reserva</th>
                <th class="btn-info">Origen</th>
                <th class="btn-info">Destino</th>
                <th class="btn-info" style="display:none">Origen Vuelo</th>
                <th class="btn-info">Piezas</th>
                <th class="btn-info">Kilos</th>
                <th class="btn-info">Volumen</th>
                <th class="btn-info">Estado</th>
                <th class="btn-info" style="display:none">Notas</th>
                <th class="btn-info">Fecha Creación</th>
                <th class="btn-info" style="display:none">Fecha Embarque</th>
                <th class="btn-info">Tipo</th>
                <th class="btn-info" style="display:none">Prioridad</th>
                <th class="btn-info" style="display:none">Forma Pago</th>
                <th class="btn-info" style="display:none">Tarifa</th>
                <th class="btn-info" style="display:none">Tipo Moneda</th>
                <th class="btn-info">Acción</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>
<tbody class="input-sm">
 <%

                      try
                      {

                      for(int i=0; i<reservasCliente.size(); i++)
                                        {
                                            out.println("<tr>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getNumeroReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getOrigenReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getDestinoReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getOrigenVueloReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getTotalPiezasReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getTotalKilosReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getTotalVolumenReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getEstadoReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getNotaReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getFechaCreacionReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getFechaEmbarqueReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getTipoReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getPrioridadReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getTipoTarifaReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getTarifaReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getTipoMonedaReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"
                                                    + "<button type='button'  class='btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open btn-xs' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalDetalleReserva' style='font-size:19px'></button>"
                                                    + " <button type='button'  class='btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn-xs' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalAsignarVuelo' style='font-size:19px'></button>"
                                                    + " <button type='button'  class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn-xs' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalReservaClienteEliminarReserva' style='font-size:19px'></button>"
                                                    + "</td>");

                                        }    

                      }
                      catch(java.lang.NullPointerException ex)
                      {
                          ex.getMessage();

                          out.print("</tr>");
                      }
             %>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" style="font-size:19px"></button>
</div>
</form>
```

Aca dejo el servlet que muestra los datos a traves del botón submit que es el que muestra los datos en la tabla.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

ReservasDao mostrarReservaClienteDao=new ReservasDao();
    Usuario usuarioCliente=new Usuario();
    try
    {
        Connection conn = ConexionMysqlCargomove_db.getInstance().getConnection();

        usuarioCliente.setIdUsuario(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txt_usuarioVerReservaCliente")));
        ResultSet resultadoReservas=mostrarReservaClienteDao.verReservasCliente(usuarioCliente);

        ArrayList<Reserva>reservasCliente=new ArrayList<Reserva>();

        if(request.getParameter("txt_usuarioVerReservaCliente").isEmpty())
        {
            String errorVerReservasCliente="No se ingresó datos de entrada";
            request.getSession().setAttribute("errorVerReservasCliente", errorVerReservasCliente);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("errorVerReservasCliente.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
        else
        {


            while(resultadoReservas.next())
            {
                reservasCliente.add(new Reserva(resultadoReservas.getInt("COD_SEQ_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("ORI_DOC_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("DES_DOC__RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("ORI_VLO_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getInt("TOTAL_PZS_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getDouble("TOTAL_KLS_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getDouble("TOTAL_VOL_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("EST_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("NOTAS_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("FECH_GEN_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("FECH_EMB_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("TPO_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("PRIO_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("TPO_TFA_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getDouble("TARIFA_CNT_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("TPO_MONEDA_RVAS")));
            }
            request.getSession().setAttribute("reservasCliente", reservasCliente);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("airExpressClientes.jsp").forward(request, response);


        }

    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(VerReservasClienteServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Para mostrar los datos en la tabla, estos se muestran por idUsuario para que solo se vean los registros hechos por el usuario que está conectado.
para esto en el codigo del formulario está el siguiente fragmento de codigo jsp el cual muestra el codigo de usuario en un campo de texto llamado txt_usuarioVerReservaCliente este esta con el style:'display:none' para que no se visualize ese id.

aca dejo solo el fragmento de codigo que tiene el formulario.

```
<%
              for(int i=0; i<usuarioCliente.size(); i++)
                           {
                               out.print("<b style='display:none'>User:</b><input type='text'value="+usuarioCliente.get(i).getIdUsuario()+" class='right' size='4' name='txt_usuarioVerReservaCliente' style='display:none'>");
                           }                        
    %>
```

Acá dejo el código de la clase del paquete Dao donde está la consulta sql.

```
public class ReservasDao {
ResultSet res;
Statement st;
PreparedStatement pst;

public ResultSet verReservasCliente(Usuario usuarioCli)
{
    try {
        Connection conn=ConexionMysqlCargomove_db.getInstance().getConnection();
        st=(Statement)conn.createStatement();
        String SQL="";

        SQL="SELECT COD_SEQ_RVAS,ORI_DOC_RVAS,DES_DOC__RVAS,ORI_VLO_RVAS,TOTAL_PZS_RVAS,TOTAL_KLS_RVAS,TOTAL_VOL_RVAS,EST_RVAS,NOTAS_RVAS,FECH_GEN_RVAS,FECH_EMB_RVAS,TPO_RVAS,PRIO_RVAS,TPO_TFA_RVAS,TARIFA_CNT_RVAS,TPO_MONEDA_RVAS\n" +
            "FROM RVAS\n" +
            "WHERE USER_COD_SEQ_USER='"+usuarioCli.getIdUsuario()+"';";

        res=st.executeQuery(SQL);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ReservasDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex.getStackTrace());
    }
    return res;
}

}
```

Acá dejo el formulario para agregar el registro, este está en el modal

```
 <nav class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center col-lg"> 
<div class="modal fade" id="modalReservar2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="#modalReservar2Label" aria-hidden="true">


<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content modal-lg">
<div class="modal-header btn-info">
<h5 class="modal-title" id="modalReservar2Label">Air Express Reservas</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="left container-fluid col-lg"> 
<div class="panel-body panel">
<form method="POST" action="GenerarReservaServlet">
<nav class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">      
<div class="left container-fluid"> 
<div class="panel-heading bg-primary">Reservar Carga</div>
<div class="panel-body panel">
            <section class="design-process-section" id="process-tab">
<div class="container col-md-12">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs">

 <ul class="nav nav-tabs process-model more-icon-preocess" role="tablist">

<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#discover" aria-controls="discover" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                   <p>Folio</p>
                   </a></li>

<li role="presentation" style="display:none"><a href="#optimization" aria-controls="optimization" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" style="display:none"><i class="fa fa-qrcode" aria-hidden="true" style="display:none"></i>
                   <p>Ruta</p>
                   </a></li>

<li role="presentation" style="display:none"><a href="#content" aria-controls="content" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" style="display:none"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o" aria-hidden="true" style="display:none"></i>
                   <p>Visualización</p>
                   </a></li>

<li role="presentation"><a href="#strategy" aria-controls="strategy" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-send-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                   <p>Datos Reserva</p>
                   </a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
                 <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="discover">
                   <div class="design-process-content col-md-12">
                   <h3 class="semi-bold">Datos del Folio</h3>


<div class="panel-heading bg-primary"></div>   
                <div class="panel-body panel panel-success">
                   <table class="table-hover table-condensed table-responsive">

 <tr>

                           <th class="input-sm">N° FOLIO</th>
                           <td><input type="text" class="input-sm" size="4" name="txt_codigo_folio" required="Codigo de Folio" id="txt_id_folio"></td>
                           <th class="input-sm">FOLIO</th>
                           <td><input type="text" class="input-sm" size="10" name="txt_folio" required="Codigo de Folio" id="txt_folio_completo"></td>
                           <td>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary input-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalConsultaFolio">
                                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                               </button>


</td>

<% 

                                     for(int i=0; i<usuarioCliente.size(); i++)
                                        {
                                            out.print("<b style='display:none'>User:</b><input type='text'value="+usuarioCliente.get(i).getIdUsuario()+" name='txt_cod_user' class='right' size='4' readonly='readonly' style='display:none'>");

                                        }

                        %>


</tr>

                   </table>


                   <form>
                   <table class="table-hover table-condensed table-responsive">
                       <tr>
                           <th class="input-sm" style="display:none">CODIGO</th>
                           <td><input type="text" class="input-sm" size="5" name="txt_cod_cliente" required value="2" style="display:none"></td>
                           <td>
                               <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary input-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalConsultaCliente" style="display:none">
                                   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                               </button>
                           </td>
                       </tr>
                   </table>
</div>


             <div class="container-fluid navbar-right">
             <a type="button" href="" class="btn btn-primary">Siguiente</a>
             </div>

</div>
</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="strategy">
                   <div class="design-process-content col-md-12">

<div class="left container-fluid">

<div class="panel-heading bg-primary">Datos de la Reserva</div>
 <div class="panel-body panel panel-success">
        <table class="table-hover table-condensed">

            <tr class="input-sm">
                <th>Guia</th>

                <td>
                    <b>Origen</b><br>
<select name="txt_origen_folio" class="input-sm"  required="">
                            <option>SCL</option>
                            <option>VAL</option>
                            <option>OSO</option>
                            <option>CNP</option>

                    </select>
</td>
<td><b>Destino</b><br>

<select name="txt_destino_folio" class="input-sm"  required="">
                            <option>VAL</option>
                            <option>OSO</option>
                            <option>CNP</option>
                            <option>SCL</option>

                    </select>

<td><b>Fecha</b><br><input type="date" id="datepicker3" name="txt_fecha_reserva" class="input-sm" size="2" required></td>

</tr>

<tr class="input-sm">
                <th>Vuelo</th>
                <td>
                   <select name="txt_origen_vuelo" class="input-sm"  required="">
                            <option>VAL</option>
                            <option>OSO</option>
                            <option>CNP</option>
                            <option>SCL</option>

                    </select> 
                </td>


                <td><b>Estado</b>
                    <select class="input-sm" name="txt_estado" required>

                            <option>PENDIENTE</option>

                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
  <br>
        <div class="left container-fluid col-md-6">

<div class="panel-heading btn-info"></div>

 <div class="panel-body panel panel-success">

    <table class="table-hover table-condensed table-responsive">
        <tr>
            <th class="input-sm">Largo</th>
            <th class="input-sm">Ancho</th>
            <th class="input-sm">Alto</th>
        </tr>    
        <tr class="input-sm">
            <td>
                    <input type="text" size="1" id="text_largo" onChange="calculoVolumen();" required>
            </td>
            <td>
                    <input type="text" size="1" id="text_ancho" onChange="calculoVolumen();" required>
            </td>
            <td>
                    <input type="text" size="1"  id="text_alto"  onChange="calculoVolumen();" required>
            </td>
        </tr> 
    </table>

<table class="table-hover table-condensed table-responsive">

        <tr class="input-sm">
                <th>Piezas</th>
                <th>Kilos</th>
                <th>Volumen</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <td>

                     <input type="number" name="txt_total_piezas" class="input-sm" required min="1" max="100">

                 </td>
                 <td><input type="text" name="txt_total_kilos" class="input-sm" size="2" id="text_kilos" onChange="calcularMonto();" required></td>
                 <td><input type="text" name="txt_total_volumen" class="input-sm" size="2" id="text_volumen" required readonly="readonly">

                 </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
</div>
</div>


<div class="right container-fluid col-md-6">
        <div class="panel-heading btn-info"><b>Total a pagar</b> <input type="text" name="txt_tarifa" class="input-sm bg bg-primary" size="10" id="text_tarifa" readonly="readonly"></div>

<div class="panel-body panel panel-success">

        <table class="table-hover table-condensed table-responsive">
            <tr class="input-sm">
                <th>Moneda</th>
                <th>Tarifa kilo</th>

            </tr>    
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select class="input-sm" name="txt_moneda" required>
                            <option>Seleccione</option>
                            <option>CLP</option>
                            <option>USD</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txt_tarifa_kilo" class="input-sm" size="3" id="text_tarifa_kilo" onChange="calcularMonto();" value="1000" readonly="readonly"></td>

            </tr>

        </table>

</div>
 </div> 

 <div class="right container-fluid col-md-12">
 <div class="panel-heading btn-info"></div>
 <div class="panel-body panel panel-success">

 <table class="table-hover table-condensed table-responsive">
            <tr class="input-sm">
                <th>Tipo Reserva</th>
                <th>Prioridad</th>
                <th>Fecha Embarque</th>
                <th>Medio de Pago</th>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select class="input-sm" name="txt_tipo_reserva">
                            <option>Seleccione</option>
                            <option>COMPLETA</option>
                            <option>PARCIAL</option>
                            </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="input-sm" name="txt_prioridad">
                            <option>Seleccione</option>
                            <option>ALTA</option>
                            <option>MEDIA</option>
                            <option>BAJA</option>
                            </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="date" name="txt_fecha_embarque" class="input-sm" required placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"></td>
                <td>
                    <select class="input-sm" name="txt_tpo_tarifa" required>
                            <option>EFECTIVO</option>
                            <option>TRANSFERENCIA</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

</div>

<div class="form-group">


<label for="comment">Notas:</label>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="2" id="comment" name="txa_notas"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid navbar-right">
<a type="button" href="" class="btn btn-success">ATRAS</a>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Guardar">
</div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Aca el servlet que permite agregar registro

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

try
     {
        Reserva ra=new Reserva();
        ReservasDao rvasDao=new ReservasDao();
        Folio fo=new Folio();
        Cliente c=new Cliente();
        Usuario us=new Usuario();
        FoliosDao fdaos=new FoliosDao();

        ra.setOrigenReserva(request.getParameter("txt_origen_folio"));
        ra.setDestinoReserva(request.getParameter("txt_destino_folio"));
        ra.setOrigenVueloReserva(request.getParameter("txt_origen_vuelo"));

        ra.setTotalPiezasReserva(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txt_total_piezas")));
        ra.setTotalKilosReserva(Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("txt_total_kilos")));
        ra.setTotalVolumenReserva(Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("txt_total_volumen")));

        ra.setEstadoReserva(request.getParameter("txt_estado"));
        ra.setNotaReserva(request.getParameter("txa_notas"));

        ra.setFechaCreacionReserva(request.getParameter("txt_fecha_reserva"));
        ra.setFechaEmbarqueReserva(request.getParameter("txt_fecha_embarque"));

        ra.setTipoReserva(request.getParameter("txt_tipo_reserva"));
        ra.setPrioridadReserva(request.getParameter("txt_prioridad"));

        ra.setTipoTarifaReserva(request.getParameter("txt_tpo_tarifa"));
        ra.setTarifaReserva(Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("txt_tarifa")));
        ra.setTipoMonedaReserva(request.getParameter("txt_moneda"));

        us.setIdUsuario(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txt_cod_user")));
        c.setCodigoCliente(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txt_cod_cliente")));
        fo.setIdFolio(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("txt_codigo_folio")));

        if(request.getParameter("txt_cod_user").isEmpty()||request.getParameter("txt_cod_cliente").isEmpty()||request.getParameter("txt_codigo_folio").isEmpty())
        {
            String error="Campos vacios";
            request.getSession().setAttribute("error",error);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("errorMantenedorFolios.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
        else
        {
            if(request.getParameter("txt_cod_user")!=null||request.getParameter("txt_codigo_folio")!=null||request.getParameter("txt_cod_cliente")!=null)
            {
                String mensaje="Registro ingresado con exito";
                request.getSession().setAttribute("mensaje", mensaje);

                PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
                //out.println("<script type=javascript>alert('Reserva realizada con exito');</script>");
                request.getRequestDispatcher("mensajeReservaCreada.jsp").forward(request, response);
                rvasDao.crearReservas(ra, us, fo, c);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    System.out.println("<h2>Datos de formulario no fueron rescatados</h2>");
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }


}
```

Disculpe lo largo del codigo, pero la finalidad de esto es que necesito que al guardar un registro,al presionar el botón volver de la pagina del mensaje, el sistema hagan el submit del botón mostrar para que asi se refresquen los datos de la tabla y asi no tengo que volver a presionar el botón mostrar para recargar la pagina.

espero me puedan ayudar. saludos

Comment: Entonces tenés el jsp airExpressClientes.jsp que muestra la tabla y el jsp mensajeReservaCreada.jsp que muestra el mensaje de reserva guardada con el botón volver. Es así? Por curiosidad, si apretas volver, te muestra la tabla?

Comment: cuando presiono volver , vuelvo a la pagina principal airExpressClientes.jsp, esta tiene una sección  que tiene la tabla, pero como la consulta recibe el id usuario como parámetro , tengo que apretar siempre el botón que tiene el icono refresh , este botón es para mostrar los datos en la tabla.

Comment: en la imagen la tabla tiene varios botones, uno con el icono de un ojo es para ver el detalle y modificar algún dato, también esta el botón que tiene el icono de eliminar y el otro botón tiene un icono "+" este botón me llama el modal para agregar un registro y este al final despliega el jsp mensajeReservaCreada.jsp.

Comment: el tema es si hago cualquiera de la operaciones de los botones que mencione antes, al finalizar una operación  como puedo hacer para que se ejecute el submit el boton mostrar para que los datos de la tabla se muestren automaticamente sin tener que presioinar el boton mostrar.

Comment: Espero me puedan ayudar por favor.

Comment: El submit lo podés poner como un timer de unica vez en javascript, pero la verdad me parece que el problema que tenes es de arquitectura como está armado el sistema, porque en una reserva, el usuario lo deberías tener en la sesión (como sea que se guarde) y la pagina que muestra la tabla no debería esperar recibir un usuario como parametro. Lo que en realidad abre otros muchos problemas por ejemplo si se conectan como un usuario y luego te lo cambian cuando solicitan la pagina.

Comment: mmm, y en el controlador como podria asociar el id usuario por sesion para que solo me muestre las reservas del usuario que está logueado?

Comment: de todas maneras el id usuario lo recibo de la session pero lo muestra en un input type ="text" y de ahi es de donde lo toma para la consulta.

Comment: como podria hacer para que en el controlador pudiera tomar directamente el id usuario de la session sin tener que tomarlo de un campo de texto?

Comment: alguien me podría ayudar por favor

Comment: El controlador tiene acceso a la sesion desde el HttpServletRequest: request.getSession(). Cuande haces el loguin lo guardas ahí y después tenes acceso durante toda la sesion.

Answer (score 0):

Un poco tarde, pero espero le sirva a alguien mas, lo que puedes hacer es que en tu mismo servelet de agregar, con el `request.dispacher` llames de nuevo al servelet pero con la variable listar algo asi.

Declaras una variable `accion` que recibe el parametro llamado `accion`, capturado del botón, que agrega un nuevo registro a la tabla.

Dentro del botón que agrega algún campo a la tabla iría así:

```
button type="submit" name="accion" value="Agregar" >Guardar /button
```

Esto en el servelet:

```
String accion = request.getParameter("accion");
```

Si de pronto no se comprende muy bien les dejo este [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQKP9uUb-mg&list=PLG1l7S-453CZbEhZ1X1PLpygPMCUzVSnZ&index=3)

Espero les ayude

```
        switch (accion) {
            case "Listar":
                List lista = reservas.listar();
                request.setAttribute("reservas", lista);
                break;
            case "Agregar":
                    String dni = request.getParameter("dato 0");
                String nom = request.getParameter("dato1");//datos de la reserva
                String tel = request.getParameter("dato2");//datos de la reserva
                String est = request.getParameter("dato3");//datos de la reserva
                c.setDni(dato0);
                c.setNom(dato1);
                c.setDir(dato2);
                c.setEs(dato3);
                cdao.agregar(c);//envias los datos

                request.getRequestDispatcher("Control?accion=Listar").forward(request, response);//aqui vuelves a llamar al listar

                break;default:
                throw new AssertionError();
        }
        request.getRequestDispatcher("PanelUsuario.jsp").forward(request, response);
    //finalmente envias todo a la pagina que quieres mostrar la tabla
    }
```